# Переменная для бд

Tags: c#, база-данных

Язык: C#

Допустим есть запрос для бд

```
SELECT id FROM Table WHERE name = a
```

Видим что в этом запросе мы обращаемся к бд Table. Но она прописана руками в запросе

Как можно передать название бд в запрос через переменную?

Comment: ну например `"Select id from " + моя_переменная + " where name = a"`, но делайте так только тогда, когда уверены, что ничего, кроме имени таблицы в переменную записано быть не может.

Comment: Спасибо я попробую, но когда я так пытался сделать у меня была ошибка(какая уже не помню)